# Is it possible to create postman environment scopes using pre-request in local?

Tags: postman, postman-pre-request-script

I want to create postman scopes in local through pre-request. is it possible to create?

[image]

Comment: Need a little more details, it's unclear what you're asking.

Comment: @socalcheesehead, updated above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set Global Variables in **Pre-request Script** section.

If you want to store some value which can be used further. Then you can store that value in global variable and afterwards you can use it.

Ex.
**pm.globals.set("Variable-Name","Variable-value");**